# How to get the ID of item clicked in DataList

Tags: sql, asp.net, datalist

I have an sql table that contains strings that lead to images. I want to view all the images in a datalist but at the same time, when one image is clicked, I want to get it`s ID from my sql table.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="5"  >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSelectAlbum" runat="server" style="margin: 1vw; width: 10vw; height: 10vw" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "coverPhoto") %>' OnClick="btnSelectAlbum_Click"  />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

currently, I don`t have any code in my c# because I couldn`t find any solution that solves my issue yet. I would like to get help from you!

Comment: You want the ID of the current item holding the Button or the ID of the Button itself?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean you can use the `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` porperties along with `OnCommand` instead of OnClick:

```
<asp:ImageButton 
    ID="btnSelectAlbum" 
    runat="server" 
    style="margin: 1vw; width: 10vw; height: 10vw" 
    ImageUrl='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "coverPhoto") %>'
    CommandName="album" 
    CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>'
    OnCommand="btnSelectAlbum_Command"  
/>
```

Then in code behind:

```
protected void btnSelectAlbum_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName.Equals("album"))
    {
        var id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

        //Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: What should I write in commandName and OnCommand? can you explain a little bit more?